# problem of wordpress move hosting, broking the link

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress as a CMS(NOT A BLOG) build a information site. I use `wordpress 3.04` + `buddypress 1.26` + `Exec-PHP`(only 2 plungins).

I built my site in my computer, `winxp + Apache/2.2.13 + PHP/5.2.11` the path is in `e:/www/wordpress`. I made a custom `buddypress theme` in `E:\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mynewtheme` and I store all the `Template, css, js, images` under this theme path. Then I open `settings->Permalink Settings->Custom Structure` set a path like `http:/localhost/wordpress/index.php` (For I am a newbie, I tried this, but pass the test). I add all my new pages through `admin dashboard->pages->add new`. Then I can test my pages, type a url like `localhost/wordpress/computers/apple`.

I have already finished my site, so I want move these files to another computer for a last test. The new computer  `win7 + Apache/2.2.13 + PHP/5.2.11` the path is in `c:/www/wordpress`, I copied all the page files from first computer `e:/www/wordpress` to new computer `c:/www/wordpress` and copied all database through `phpmyadmin`.

I just copied page files and database, nothing more. But when I type the url `http:/localhost/wordpress`, the home page just load little, and `localhost/wordpress/computers/apple` was a broken link. I checked the `html source code` , find all the `css, js, images` under my custom theme are all missed. Is it because my first `settings->Permalink Settings->Custom Structure` setting wrong? Or other mistake caused?

How to solve? I am almost crazy.  Waiting for a help.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you get a 404 page when you type `localhost/wordpress/computers/apple` ?

Comment: The WordPress codex has an extensive tutorial on the issue: [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: @JohnP, no, not a 404, but `oops! this link appears to be broken`, I think the new computer not recognize the theme path. even I have reactive `buddypress` and `theme`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first installed WordPress in a WAMP server, there can be problems when migrating server. I know of two options:

1. While in your WAMP server, before doing the migration, under Settings, enter the domain that you will be moving to your site. It will most likely work once you migrate.
2. (This is what I use), after performing the migration, you can edit the domain in PHPMyAdmin. Log in to PhpMyAdmin and choose the database that you use for WordPress. Under list, look for wp_options.
   Under the field option_name, seek site URL. The site URL should be listed as localhost. Change it to your site's new URL.

Comment: my two computer all have the same site's url `localhost/wordpress`, I can open the url in the new computer. but open the link `localhost/wordpress/computers/apple` ,it show `oops! this link appears to be broken` but not a 404 page fault. I guess the theme path is broken. I have already `deactive` `active` buddypress and my `theme`, still not recognize my theme path...

Comment: Check how your settings are set? While operating on a local server, it might be best to test with the WordPress default (p=1234) format. The problem is one of file permissions. Change your permissions (temporarily) in your WordPress directory to allow write.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be an issue of your mod_rewrite file. Some versions of XAMPP do not enable mod_rewrite by default (though it is compiled in Apache). To enable it — and thus enable WordPress to write the .htaccess file needed to create pretty permalinks — you must open apache/conf/httpd.conf and uncomment the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (i.e., delete the hash/pound sign at the front of the line).

Comment: right, the new XAMPP hasn't open the `mod_rewrite` I have fixed it, thanks, @avi.

Answer (score 0):

Did wordpress installed correctly? Is it a theme issue?

Comment: I install correctly in my first computer, and the theme also run well. Then I just copy and paste my `wordpress` folder and database to my new computer(without a new install) the problem is appear...

Comment: OK, then the problem is pretty obvious. Try changing the settings in wp-config.php or do a new Wordpress install and then upload your theme files in the theme folder.